Running Python script in CRON doesn't create files
I have a Python script that gets data from database and saves it in 20 parquet files. It runs properly when I execute it manually but when I add this to crontab it doesn't:
0 6 * * * python3 myScript.py >> mylogfile.log 2>&1

Cron job does work as it creates 20 file but 19 of them are empty and only one is saved properly. Probably it's because cron caches it and in the end saves the first or the last cached file.
Any ideas how to fix it? Really need this.
I tried adding sys.stdout.flush() after saving each file in script but it still doesn't work. The only difference is that text outputs are written in log-file immediately.

Probably not. Can you [edit] and share a [mre] of your Python script? Maybe missing permissions for your root user?

But it saves one file properly. If the problem is in missing permissions, it wouldn't save even this one, right?

Impossible to say without knowing what your script does.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
